# Coldfusion11 and Coldfusion8 on same windows server

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-11

I need to install cf11 on the same windows 2008 server as an existing cf8 install.

I realise it would be better to have 2 servers but in this case thats not an option open to us so I need specific help with the 2 installs.

The current CF8 is using IIS7.

I have done a bit of spade work and I believe the best way to do this cleanly would be to install a 2nd web server, e.g apache on windows and then configure it with CF11.

I had hoped that I could actually install CF11 and just configure specific iis sites with it, hoping this would leave the cf8 configured sites intact.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's stopping you from running both on IIS? It might be an idea to raise a question to serverfault.com along the lines of "getting CF8 and CF11 to both work through same IIS" or something (and provide full situation, troubleshooting already done, error messages, etc.

Comment: Well, There may or may not be anything stopping me running both with IIS but that's sort of what im asking, I haven't physically tried it yet but I get a suspicion it may not be that straight forward and would prefer to check before I mess my server. I suppose a better way of wording this would be. "Can one run CF8 and CF11 on the same server and same IIS?"

Comment: You don't have any other PC lying around you can test this with? That's what I'd be doing (NB: not saying it's not a good question, but  perhaps one that should be pretty easy to ask one's self. I've got both running on the same machine, but only on dev web server, sorry).

Comment: Thanks Adam, I suppose if this forum didn't exist then I would have had to test it myself with a spare machine but I guess that's why we ask others opinions who may have the answer already, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run multiple sites under IIS on the same server, with different versions of ColdFusion. Every connector you create, should be with ***individual sites*** and not with "**ALL**" websites. Different versions of ColdFusion connected with different sites under the same IIS on the same server will not conflict with each other.